# Parse time string

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript or jquery, is there a way to verify if a given string is in h:m or hh:mm format or simply h format.
ex:

```
5 //legal    
2.5 //legal
.5 //legal
2:05 //legal
:5 //NOT legal
2:61 // NOT legal
```

The idea is, if the string can be parsed as a double or it can be parsed in the h:m format then it is ok.

This is NOT 24 hour time, 33:44 is perfectly valid, this is for work time entry.

Thanks

Comment: `:5` is not legal, but as you asked about `h:m`, I assume that `2:5` is; is that correct? Also, is `2.75` legal (2 and 3/4 hours) or illegal (shorthand for `2:75` which is illegal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be solved with such code:

```
function validate(value) {
           if (!parseFloat(value)) {
              var values = value.split(':');
              if (!parseInt(values[0]) || parseInt(values[1]) >= 60) {
                 return false;
              }
           }
           else {
             var values = value.split('.');
             if (parseInt(values[1]) >= 60)
                return false;
           }
           return true;
}
```

Comment: `validate( 'Infinityisnotavalidtime' );    // true`

Comment: `validate( '10pmismybedtime' );    // true`

Comment: A poorly defined question deserves a poorly designed answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(str) {
  if (!isNaN(str)) return true;
  $parts = str.split(':');
  return !isNaN(str[0]) && !isNaN(str[1]) && (+str[1]) <= 60;
}
```

Comment: Er, if you return right away, valid times won't pass (the string won't contain any :, because any string with that will be filtered out immediately

Comment: No it won't. `isNaN('2.5')` === false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a duration (so that `h` can be any value), test for both numbers and times with a regular expression like:

```
/^(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d+:[0-5]?\d)$/.test(str)
```

which returns `true` for the legal cases and `false` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/^(\d+|\d*(\.[0-5]?\d)|\d+(:[0-5]?\d)?)$/
```

E.g.

```
function verify( time ) {
    return /^(\d+|\d*(\.[0-5]?\d)|\d+(:[0-5]?\d)?)$/.test( time ); 
}  

verify( '24:00' );    // true
```

Comment: No need to assume that based on the last (non "Thanks") line in the question.

Comment: @DocMax. Yeas, just noticed.